# Following ExternalLoginCallback redirection fails without exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a modified Internet application template for MVC4 and implemented the AuthConfig details for Twitter authentication. Following a redirect from twitter, and successful login, I get a redirect to the below URL and the webapp just dies with a Page Cannot Be Displayed error in IE with no further details:

provider=twitter&**sid**=XXX&oauth_token=XXX&oauth_verifier=XXX">http://domain.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?**provider**=twitter&**sid**=XXX&oauth_token=XXX&oauth_verifier=XXX

ExternalLoginCallback function as implemented in the template works as expected and I see a call to the local redirect which calls Home/Index. However rather than this view being rendered I see nothing happening on the site. I've used the network tracing functionality in IE to see the request details but that didn't really help me understand the issue even more.

I'm aware this is a little vague but I'd appreciate it if you let me know what I can check additionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am stupid.

This is what I had in the Home controller:

```
 if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            else
                return View();
```

and it was supposed to be:

```
 if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "LandingPage");
            else
                return View();
```

I am sorry I asked this question but I hope there is someone else out there as stupid as I am and they may benefit from this.